# Adding new DataGrid row at runtime with Cascading Combo boxes?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid, combobox

Bear with me if you would, I'm brand new to WPF MVVM development.

The utility I'm working on (WPF client application) contains a 4 column datagrid that displays the currently available data to the user for a specified period of time.  The records returned may contain all or just some of the data ultimately required for the record to be complete.  The user should be able to modify the missing pieces or add new rows altogether to fill in missing records.  3 of the 4 columns contain combo boxes with only valid choices.  The combo boxes are cascading so that the first combo determines the contents of combo 2 and 3.  The 4th column is a simple price column.

I've managed to get the grid working perfectly with the default return data.  The combox populate correctly as well as display the current record's value as the selected item in the combo.

My problem is with adding a new row.  I've been trying to accomplish this inline.  Meaning the user clicks on or tabs to the blank row at the bottom of the list and a new row gets added to collection accepts input.  The first combo is populated in the empty row, but selecting a value does not cascade the changes to the other 2 combos.  It works up in the populated rows though.

That make sense?  I'm probably missing something so stupid simple that I'll kick myself when someone points it out but right now I'm tearing out what little hair I have left.

So, Is it possible to have a new user add a row just by tabbing through to the next line?
Do I need to anything special to wire up the cascading combo boxes in the new row?

Thanks!

Here's my XAML (essentially pseudo code after stripping it down so don't mind mispellings):

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="768"
    d:DesignWidth="1024">

<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainWindowViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Prices}"
                    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPrice}"
                    CanUserAddRows="True">
            <DataGrid.Columns>


                <!--  Price Group  -->
                <DataGridTemplateColumn MinWidth="120"
                                        Header="Price Group">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox x:Name="cboPriceGroup"
                                        ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.PriceGroups}"
                                        DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                                        SelectedItem="{Binding PriceGroupObject, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                <!--  Option 1  -->
                <DataGridTemplateColumn MinWidth="120"
                                        Header="Option1">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox x:Name="cboOption1"
                                        ItemsSource="{Binding PriceGroupObject.Options1}"
                                        DisplayMemberPath="Code"
                                        SelectedValuePath="Id"
                                        SelectedValue="{Binding Option1Id, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                <!--  Option 2  -->
                <DataGridTemplateColumn MinWidth="120"
                                        Header="Option2">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox x:Name="cboOption2"
                                        ItemsSource="{Binding PriceGroupObject.Options2}"
                                        DisplayMemberPath="Code"
                                        SelectedValuePath="Id"
                                        SelectedValue="{Binding Option2Id, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                <!--  Price  -->
                <DataGridTemplateColumn MinWidth="120"
                                        Header="Price">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox x:Name="txtPrice"
                                        Text="{Binding Price, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </StackPanel>

</Grid>
```

And here's the ViewModel:

```
    // ViewModelBase implements INotifyPropertyChanged
public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase    
{
    #region Declarations
    // Comes From Backend.Services
    private IPriceListService _PriceListService;

    private ObservableCollection<Price> _Prices;
    private Price _SelectedPrice;

    private IEnumerable<PriceGroup> _PriceGroups;
    private PriceGroup _SelectedPriceGroup;

    // Same for Options1, Options2

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    public ObservableCollection<Price> Prices
    {
        get { return _Prices; }
        set
        {
            if (_Prices != value)
            {
                _Prices = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Prices");
            }
        }
    }
    public Price SelectedPrice
    {
        get { return _Price; }
        set
        {
            if (_Price != value)
            {
                _Price = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedPrice");
            }
        }
    }

    // Same for PriceGroups, Options1, Options2

    #endregion

    #region Constructor
    public MainViewModel()
        : this(new FakePriceListService())
    {

    }
    // Constructor
    public MainViewModel(IPriceListService priceListService)
    {
        _PriceListService = priceListService;
        InitializeViewModel();
    }

    protected override void InitializeViewModel()
    {
        // Test ID
        LoadFuturesPrices(12345);
        LoadPriceGroups();
        base.InitializeViewModel();
    }
    #endregion

    #region Methods

    void LoadFuturesPrices(short FinancialPeriodId)
    { 
        Prices = _PriceListService.GetFuturesPriceList(FinancialPeriodId);
    }

    void LoadPriceGroups()
    {
        PriceGroups = _PriceListService.GetPriceGroups();
    }

    void PriceGroupSelected(string PriceGroupId)
    {
        SelectedPriceGroup = (from p in PriceGroups where p.Name == PriceGroupId select p).SingleOrDefault();
    }
    #endregion

}
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I am going through the same thing. Did you have to do a workaround?